# Proving $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

We wish to prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous by definition.

Scratch work:
$$|f(x)-f(a)| =|\frac{1}{x^2} -\frac{1}{a^2}|=|\frac{x^2-a^2}{a^2x^2}|=|x-a|\frac{|x+a|}{a^2x^2}$$
We know that $|x-a|<\delta$ therefore we have that $|a|-\delta <x<|a|+\delta.$
We need to ensure that $a^2x^2 \neq 0$. We know $a \neq 0$ by definition of the functions domain, so we only care that $x \neq 0$.
From the above inequality, we need to have that $|a|-\delta >0$, and this is only possible if $|a|>\delta$. Let us choose $\delta=\frac{|a|}{2}$.
With $\delta$ chosen we see that
$$|x-a|<\frac{|a|}{2} \text{ and that } |x|<\frac{3|a|}{2} $$
Consider $|x+a| \le |x|+|a|$  by the triangle inequality. Then $|x|+|a|<\frac{5|a|}{2}$.
$$\text{Note also that }\frac{1}{x}<\frac{2}{|a|} $$

Here, $$|x-a| \frac{|x+a|}{a^2x^2}=|x-a||x+a|\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{4}{a^2} <|x-a| \frac{5|a|}{2}\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{4}{a^2}=|x-a|\frac{10|a|}{|a|^4}<\delta\frac{10}{|a|^3}$$
We now want to have that $$\delta\frac{10}{|a|^3}<\varepsilon $$
So we choose $$\delta=\min\{\frac{10 \varepsilon}{|a|^3},\frac{|a|}{2}\}$$.

I won't include details of the full proof as it basically just depends on choosing the right $\delta$. Can anyone verify if my steps are correct?

Comment: $|x-a|<\delta$ gives $a-\delta<x<a+\delta$ and not  $|a|-\delta<x<|a|+\delta$

Comment: @SacAndSac Is it the case that $|a|-\delta < |x| < |a| +\delta$? This appears in my lecture notes.

Comment: It is not. However, remark that since $f(x)=f(-x)$, you can deal only with $a,x>0$.

Comment: The above may be the way of searching for a "good" $\delta$. After finding a good candidate the work starts. You may want to focus on this part better that on that of finding the candidate... The proof should start with: *Let $a\ne 0$ be an element of definition of $f$. (We show $f$ continuous in $a$.) Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Let $\delta=\delta (\epsilon)$ be... Let $x$ be in the domain of definition of $f$ so that $|x-a|<\delta$. We show $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Here is the chain of estimations for it...* This would be the way a proof is given. The candidate should make a short chain...

Comment: So instead of asking for the correction of the steps, tacitly assuming for what stuff they should apply, we would have better the clear chain of estimations after claiming that that above $\delta$ or some other candidate works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach.

$|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}|=|\frac{|a-x||a+x|}{a^2x^2}|\ge\epsilon\implies |x-a|\ge \frac{\epsilon a^2 x^2}{|x+a|}$.

Since $f(x)=f(-x)$, WLOG $a>0$.

Let $-a/2<x-a<a/2$.

Minimize the numerator and maximize the denominator.

$\frac{a^2x^2}{|x+a|}>\frac{a^2(a-a/2)^2}{|a+a/2|}=\frac{a^3}{6}$

So let $\delta=$ min $(a/2,6\epsilon/a^3)$.

This probably suffices since the first statement is the contrapositive of the definition of continuity

We have $ |\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}|\ge \epsilon \implies |x-a|\ge \frac{\epsilon a^2x^2}{|x+a|}>a^3\epsilon/6, $ so by contraposition $|x-a|<a^3\epsilon/6\implies |1/x^2-1/a^2|<\epsilon$, the formal definition of continuity at a point.